# Why is myString.equals("aString"); different from "aString".equals(myString);?

Tags: java, string, equals

I heard several times that in using `boolean equals(Object o)` to compare `Strings`, it's better to put the constant on the left side of the function as in the following:

- Bad: myString.equals("aString");
- Good: "aString".equals(myString);

Why is this?

Comment: you can get some really nasty side effects having the contant on the left. Nullpointers get thrown for a reason.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because if `myString` is null you get an exception. You know `"aString"` will never be null, so you can avoid that problem.

Often you'll see libraries that use `nullSafeEquals(myString,"aString");` everywhere to avoid exactly that (since most times you compare objects, they aren't generated by the compiler!)

Comment: @Jesus Yes it avoids the 'need', but honestly, checking for nulls when you don't want them is a good practice anyway :)

Comment: yeah I would rather pass around empty strings to avoid this problem to begin with but that's just me, defensive programming is often a sign of bad code in some cases but if empty string is a valid return then null is really your only other option I guess

Comment: I would actually consider passing empty strings to be defensive programming as well. :) You're right that it can be a sign of bad code, but it can also be a life saver. It honestly depends on how it's being used (like so many tools we have at our disposal). If you're relying on defensive programming for correctness as opposed to having proper exception handling, that's a bad idea. On the other hand, if you can handle the exception before it happens, that's a good thing!

Comment: Yeah I tend to avoid having exceptions at all costs unless it's completely out of my control. I'm mostly used to C programming so you can kind of consider it all defensive as checking for error codes is faster than incurring exceptions (since exceptions cause stack unwinding and some other not so nice things)

Comment: I'd rather have an exception than an error code, personally. The performance hit is negligible, and the benefit of having compile-time integrity is well worth it. Coming from a C background I can see why you'd structure it with error codes instead, but I would strongly consider incorporating exceptions in instead of error codes. Just my thoughts :)

Comment: I find exception handling lets people be lazy. For instance trying to read from a file that doesnt exist, some dont bother checking that the file exists and just handle the exception but if you can prevent it why not?

Comment: I like exceptions much, much, much more than error codes. Why? Because error codes are too easy to ignore. Exceptions **cannot** be ignored. Sure, you can do a catch-all block that does nothing, which effectively ignores the exception, but any statements that follow the failed statement (up to the end of the `try` block) will _not_ execute. This isn't the case with an ignored error code.

Comment: @Jesus Ramos Since an exception should be, well, exceptional the claim "error codes are faster than exceptions" is not true. In the general case when the exception isn't thrown "no code" is clearly faster than an condition and branch..

Comment: no necessarily true, using unlikely and likely in GCC at least you can make error code run at the same speed without branch misses (unless its an exception) usually bad exception performance comes from exceptions being thrown deep on the stack and being caught at an earlier point

Comment: @Jesus I definitely believe that using exceptions to determine program flow is a poor decision. An example would be `while(true) { try {arr[i++] = i;} catch(ArrayException e) { break; } }` Very poor. If you design your code such that your happy path throws an exception, you've done something wrong. But I would rather use an exception for my... "sad path"? than I would use an error code for my sad path.

Comment: hey, we're talking about comparing strings here! By the way, this has been the most disappointing java revelation ever... I was already thinking about implications with string pools, immutable objects, and interning operations and the answer is only that i might get what I call a "`NullReferenceException`"?? bah.. No need for defensive programming or nullSafeEquals, I'll keep doing in "my way"! lol

Comment: Altough your answer is true, The described approach does NOT replace the null check, It will fail in the next line when you want e.g parse the string: Example  if (!"".equals(value)) {
            Integer.parseInt(value);
        }  will throw an NumberformatException

Comment: @SupunWijerathne That is correct - in Java, each type has a default, uninitialized value. For primitives, this is 0 and for Objects this is null.

Answer (score 3):

This is a defensive technique to protect against `NullPointerException`s. If your constant is always on the left, no chance you will get a NPE on that `equals` call.

Comment: But you get the NPE  it in the next line, where e.g you want to parse the string. so this is not a defensive technilk. It does not replace a null check. Example: if (s!= null && !"".equals(s)) {
                            value = Integer.parseInt(s);
                        }  If you omit the null check you get theNPE in parseInt()

Comment: yes, you are just deferring the nullpointer to some other even harder to diagnose bug. These CONSTANT.equals(variable) have cause such horrible bugs in my projects that i consider it a first rate antipattern.

Comment: "no chance you will get a NPE on _that_ equals call". This was not advocating reducing validation elsewhere, just why constants are used on the left.

Answer (score 1):

This is poor design, because you are hiding NullPointerExceptions. Instead of being alerted that string is null, you will instead get some weird program behaviour and an exception being thrown somewhere else.

But that all depends if 'null' is a valid state for your string. In general 'null's should never be considered a reasonable object state for passing around.

Comment: You are totally right, The sad truth is that one gets another Exception in the next line. It dos not replace a null check. The bad thing is that you are fooled into not needing anymore the null check. Even static analysis tools (sonarcube) recommend this wrong approach.

Comment: sonarcube recommends this?? that is bad! It is one of the worst antipatterns in my opinion. It just hides the bug, and turns it into an even harder to find bug.

Comment: An this was the only sonarcube recomendation wich caused a bug in my last sw release.