# confusion between && and || in java

Tags: java

```
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

    public class Insurance {

    final static String INPUT_GENDER = "Please enter your gender: (Male or Female)";
    final static String MALE = "male";
    final static String FEMALE = "female";
    static String gender;
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        do
        {
            gender = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(INPUT_GENDER).toLowerCase();
            System.out.println(gender);
        }
        while(!gender.equals(MALE) && !gender.equals(FEMALE));  
    }
}
```

The above piece of code is the beginning to a revision assignment, but I came across something I don't understand. The user is asked to enter their gender, as "Male"  or "Female", and the program should only continue if the input satisfies one of these inputs. This is done by comparing the input to the final strings for MALE and FEMALE.

What I don't understand is why it only works using && in the while statement. I expected it to need ||, because we want it to continue if the input matches either of the two gender strings. I understood that && should only allow the code to continue if both arguments are true.

TL;DR

```
    while(!gender.equals(MALE) && !gender.equals(FEMALE));  //This works
    while(!gender.equals(MALE) || !gender.equals(FEMALE));  //This does not work
    while(gender.equals(MALE)  ||  gender.equals(FEMALE));  //This does not work
```

Comment: @Oded. Lazy fat drunk sitting on his couch all day.

Comment: @gdoron - Thanks for that... constructive... comment...

Comment: I guess you created this as an example, but if not, then: It might be [a good idea to check for `null` on input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7577089/why-is-mystring-equalsastring-different-from-astring-equalsmystring). Or to use a radio button (a drop-down select) for it since it is a form with two options, right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- `&&` is a logical `and` operator
- `||` is the logical `or` operator

Using [De Morgan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), the following:

```
while(!gender.equals(MALE) && !gender.equals(FEMALE))
```

Can be translated to:

```
while(!(gender.equals(MALE) || gender.equals(FEMALE)))
```

(note the additional parenthesis and the placement of the `!` before them).

Both the above mean that the `gender` is neither `MALE` or `FEMALE`.

Your other code:

```
while(!gender.equals(MALE) || !gender.equals(FEMALE))
```

The above means - `gender` is not `MALE` *or* `gender` is not `FEMALE`.

```
while(gender.equals(MALE)  ||  gender.equals(FEMALE));
```

Similarly, the above means - `gender` is `MALE` *or* `gender` is `FEMALE`.

Comment: notice the parenthesis-change and _"!"_ removal (unnecessary clarification? :p)

Comment: I actually used the De Morgan rules in a very complicated SQL query... believe it or not.

Comment: Ahh, De Morgans rules, those i would never have thought of! Many thanks to all who answered

Answer (score 0):

In English: "when not FEMALE or MALE, do again"
then in Java `do{...}while(!(FEMALE || MALE));`
and !(A||B) is equal to !A && !B

Answer (score 0):

`&&` is Java's logical *AND* operator
`||` is Java's logical *OR* operator

for example:

```
boolean a = true;
boolean b = false;
boolean c = a && b;   // c is false
boolean d = a || c;   // d is true
```

Additionally, `!` is Java's logical `NOT` operator. It is used for negating boolean expressions:

```
boolean p = true;
boolean q = !p;   // q is false
```

It is also worth noting that `x && y` will result in the same logical value as `!(!x || !y)`.
Similarly, `x || y` can be rewritten as `!(!x && !y)`

Comment: ...better put in the 'definition' of `!` as well

Answer (score 0):

In your `do-while` loop you want prompt the user to re-enter his/her gender if the gender entered is neither `MALE` nor `FEMALE`.

So the while condition would be that if **both** `gender.equals(MALE)` and `gender.equals(FEMALE)` return false **then** you would re-prompt the user i.e. the loop will iterate.

That means if **not** of `gender.equals(MALE)` and **not** of `gender.equals(FEMALE)` **both** are true then your loop should iterate.

Hence,

`while(!(gender.equals(MALE)) && !(gender.equals(FEMALE)))`